# React - Use react hooks, set an array state in useEffect and watch it cause Infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs

Declare an custom hook:

```
const useTest = (init: any) => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState<any[]>([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setArr(Array.from(init.arr));
  }, [init]);
  return arr;
};
```

Use it:

```
useTest({ arr: [1] })
```

No matter what object or array did I pass to the init.arr, it would cause a infinite loop.
I tried to wrap the `init` object by useMemo, it`s useless.
But if i pass a (string | number | null | undefined), it won`t get error.

I test it use '@testing-library/react-hooks' with jest. What`s more it only occur in my test case, but runs well in browser.

So what cause that?

Comment: tried this ? }, [])

Comment: Passing an object to the dependency array can be problematic. Try passing `init.arr` instead. "The problem is that if you need to provide an object for one of those dependencies and that object is new every render, then even if none of the properties changed, your effect will get called anyway." https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect#the-problem

Comment: This is caused by my test code, each time the effect runs, it\`s reference will be reset. so that rerender is be toggled. I should call the hook like this:
`const props = { arr: [] }; renderHook(() => useTest(props));`
See:
https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library/issues/413

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass  `}, []);` as shown below to load useffect only once when component is loaded. it also should remove any infinite loop problems

```
React.useEffect(() => {
   setArr(Array.from(init.arr));
 }, []);
```

Comment: If I use the init object in the useEffect, it will cause react-hooks/exhaustive-deps.